# Click+shift does not work in games under xfce4

Tags: linux-mint, games

I am using Linux Mint with xfce4 desktop.
I found out that, in games (for instance Civilization 5 or Durkes Dungeon or Sunless Sea), `left mouse click + shift` acts like "click" without shift. `Shift+Click` actively used in games but I cannot find why it doesn't works. I tested it scancodes in xterm - it seems that Shift modifier is received alongside with click. but in games I cannot make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question unrelated to xfce4 or anything else from its dependencies. Problem was cause by XNeur keyboard layout switcher. It defines `Tab` for its action `abbreviation completion` and `Shift Tab` for some other actions. After clearing these bindings everything works. Without it these shortcuts ever doesn't caught by `xev`.